# What sort of math will help me solve programming problems?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have been looking at various programming problems and algorithms in an effort to improve my programming and problem solving skills. But, I keep running into description like this one:

"Let A = [a1,a2,...,an] be a permutation of integers 1,2,...,n. A pair of indices (i,j), 1<=i<=j<=n, is an inversion of the permutation A if ai>aj. We are given integers n>0 and k>=0. What is the number of n-element permutations containing exactly k inversions?"
(SOURCE: http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PERMUT1/)

What kind of math do I need to study in order for this sort of problem description to make sense to me?

Comment: There's not a lot of math, which part confuses you?

Comment: Also, I don't understand, you want us to help you grasp description or solve problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in this sort of quandary about a month ago. Until I came about this post from Steve Yegge - **[Math for Programmers](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/math-for-programmers.html)**

Very informative, highly recommended read. Hopefully after the read, you'll get pointers to take it from there. All the best.

Comment: mivieyoda, perfect. I've read Steve Yegge before and appreciated his thoughts. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 6):

Discrete math.  It deals with a lot of combinatorics, probability, etc, which is what you have in your problem there.  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics )

Being able to read a set equation probably doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a look at one (or both) of the following:

Graham, Knuth Patashnik: Concrete Mathematics

Knuth: The Art of Computer Programming (Vol 1)

They are not easy reads, and you definitely want a background in high school mathematics at least, but they nicely lead from there to the sort of mathematics you describe in your question, and have lots of exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a typical permutations problem. http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html